# A question related to weierstrass function

Tags: differential-geometry

Use Weierstrass function to determine how far back from the screen should a student sit in order to maximum the view range as given the floor is flat. The bottom of the screen is 1 meter above student's eye, and top of the screen is 1 meter above the bottom of the screen.

I saw this extra question and wondering how to do it properly?

Comment: What is "Weiertiass function"?

Comment: http://www.math.washington.edu/~conroy/general/weierstrass/weier.htm

Comment: Note the spelling in the linked pdf. But what does this have to do with the problem about maximizing view range?

Comment: I dont know, that why I'm trying to ask people about this question

Comment: Can you share the context in which you found this problem, then? Why do you think that the Weierstrass function is relevant to the stated problem?

Comment: I think I read the question wrong. The question said the student is watching the Weierstrass animation on the screen. it didn't said anything about the Weiertiass function to do with the answer. But I still dont understand what this question means by a student watching the animation.

Answer (score 1):

This does not use the Weierstrass nowhere-differentiable function (I don't know how that can be involved) nor the Weierstrass elliptic functions (likewise, but maybe those are less remote from the problem), but it answers the question about the screen:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regiomontanus%27_angle_maximization_problem